# How can i send a notification to alert that the task has create the table?

Tags: stored-procedures, task, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've a stored procedure which contains SQL Statements to create a table.
I have put this stored procedure inside a task snowflake.
I would like to send a message/mail/notifications no matter to announce that the table is created ?

That is my code :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_stored_procedure()
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE SQL
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$
BEGIN

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE test AS 
SELECT xxx
FROM xxx;

RETURN 'TABLE test created';
END;
$$;
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK procedure_task_test
 WAREHOUSE = XXXXX
 SCHEDULE =   'USING CRON 30 5 * * * Europe/Paris'
 USER_TASK_TIMEOUT_MS = 60000
 COMMENT = 'TABLE test is updated'
AS 
    CALL test_stored_procedure();
```

How can i send a message like 'table test is created' for example ?
no matter how it is done

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: You can use [External Functions](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/external-functions-introduction.html) to send email/message.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to send a notification, you need to use External Function with e.g. AWS SES and Lambda:

1. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/external-functions-introduction.html
2. https://medium.com/hashmapinc/sending-email-notifications-from-snowflake-using-external-functions-4b985c182292

For easier solution you could try to log in a table and query that.

Comment: ok thanks @Marcel :)

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the stored procedure, add a call to send an email (new Snowflake functionality).

Right now you have:

```sql
BEGIN

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE test AS 
SELECT xxx
FROM xxx;

RETURN 'TABLE test created';
END;
```

Modify it to:

```sql
BEGIN

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE test AS 
SELECT xxx
FROM xxx;

call system$send_email(
    'my_email_int',
    'max@example.com',
    'TABLE test created',
    'TABLE test created body'
);

RETURN 'TABLE test created';
END;
```

Comment: I wrote a full example with more details at: https://hoffa.medium.com/hey-snowflake-send-me-an-email-243741a0fe3